# assign function w/multiple parameters to a variable —both inside a Python class

Tags: python, oop, methods, variable-assignment

While my code works, I'd like to clean it a bit.
I've built a couple of functions based on thethe File().trashUntrash method,
and I've done the same for other methods in the class I'm working on:

```
class File():
    def__init__(self):
        self.this = this
        self.that = that


    def trashUntrash(self, fileId, bool):
        return file.update(fileId, isTrashed=bool)

    #these two are wrappers for self.trashUntrash:
    trash   = lambda self, fileId: self.trashUntrash(fileId, True)
    untrash   = lambda self, fileId: self.trashUntrash(fileId, False)

    #these other lambdas correspond to other methods:
    fileTitle = lambda self, id: self.fileInfo(prop="title", spreadsheetId=id)                      
    fileIds =  lambda self, id: self.fileInfo(prop="fileId", spreadsheetId=id)
    addPage = lambda self, id, title: self.action(i=0, ssId=id, title=title)
    delPage = lambda self, id, pageId: self.action(i=1, ssId=id, pageId=pageId)
    renameFile = lambda self, id, pageId, title: self.action(i=2, id=id ...)
```

So I tried assigning the method to variables that I'd then use in the rest of my code:

```
    trash = self.trashUntrash(fileId, True)
    untrash = self.trashUntrash(fileId, False)
    # and so on...
```

... as it looks shorter and more easily readable (my goal). But...  I get `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`. Removing self (which of course, doesn't make sense):

```
    trash = trashUntrash(fileId, True)
    untrash = trashUntrash(fileId, False)
    # etc.
```

... will on the other hand, produce `NameError: name 'fileId' is not defined`. If on the other hand, I simply state:

```
    trash = self.trashUntrash
    untrash = self.trashUntrash
    # etc... doing this one DOES work BUT 
    # w/o a chance to pass params, which defeats my intent.
```

... I'll get no errors, but I'll have to manually pass args, including the ones I'm using as default, making the function-to-variable assignment pointless.

So my question: *Is it possible to assign a method along with its params to a variable inside a class, and how would you do it*?

BTW, I'm using Python 3.10.8 (Nov 1 2022, GCC 12.2.0 on Linux); thank you in advance!

I've already gotten the job done via lambda functions;
however, they get quite lengthy as  I'm using
multiple positional and keyword args. I'd like a way to make these assignments shorter to read.

Comment: "So I tried assigning the method to variables that I'd then use in the rest of my code:" That is not what you are doing `trash = self.trashUntrash(fileId, True)` does not assign a function to a variable. It **calls** the function and assigns the result to a variable.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `lambda` expressions here, btw, just regular function definition statements.

Comment: Anyway, it **sounds** like you should just do `self.trash = self.trashUntrash(fileId, True)` in the `__init__`

Comment: I figured out lambdas wouldn't make too much sense inside classes; that's also a reason for me to look for other ways to declare said procedures. Thank you for the solid advice, Juanpa!

Comment: @Adriaan, thank you for the feedback; I have no way to upvote answers, I'm told "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." I'll remove the "Solved" from the subject.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, why is it recommended to avoid lambdas as shorthands? I presume and could understand that this isn't "pythonic"; also, I see how  partialmethod merely assigns the output of a function call to the var. These two considerations lead me to ask: is it possible to get away with shorthands for partial functions?

Comment: @Alejandro it's a stylistic prescription from PEP8, the official style guide. lamdba expressions exist to allow for *anonymous functions*, the idea is if you assign them to a name, that defeats their entire purpose! But of course, this is merely a stylistic issue. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In the class use `partialmethod` to define your shortcut.  If a further shortcut is needed you can assign the partial method to a local variable:

```
from functools import partialmethod

class File():
    def trash_untrash(self, file_id, is_trashed):
        print(f"{file_id = }, {is_trashed = }")
        
    trash = partialmethod(trash_untrash, is_trashed=True)
    
f = File()

f.trash(file_id=10)

trash = f.trash
trash(file_id=10)
```

Output:

```
file_id = 10, is_trashed = True
file_id = 10, is_trashed = True
```

Comment: Btw, I can successfully call the function thru the variable; the ones params that I decided to use as default, I had to include in partialmethod(func, args=args).  I now have now to explicitly declare the one param that I pass to the variable:
 trash(file_id=suchandsuch) 
I presume this is unavoidable but wonder if there's a way to simply pass the flie_id as trash(sampleFileId) instead?

Comment: No need to use the keyword argument approach I showed, `trash(10)` will also work just fine for example.

Comment: the procedure that I feed this trash(), does pack all the arguments as kwargs, and then trash( ) is to use said kwargs, tho.